# iPhone 4 Restore loop 6.1.2

Tags: iphone, itunes, jailbreak, startup, restore

OK so the other day I tried to restore my iPhone while it was jail broken on ios 6.1.2. Well it was a terrible idea.... NEVER DO IT. any way i have worked on trying to restore it back to normal but it does not work, I am stuck at the connect to iTunes screen and yeah. if you have encountered something like this it would really be nice to have my iPhone back in working condition! Please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

So you are saying that although your iDevice is in 'connect to iTunes' mode (recovery mode) , iTunes detects it but can't restore it ? I need more clarification.

In any case, you can try a hard reset ( holding both the on/off and Home button until the phone switches off ) to force the phone to switch off.

Switch it on again and see if the 'connect to iTunes' screen still appears.

If it still appears, attempt to restore using DFU mode.

> Steps to enter DFU mode:
>
> 1. Open iTunes and connect your iDevice to your computer.
> 2. Press and hold the Home button and the on/off button at the same time.
> 3. After 10 seconds release the Sleep/Wake button. Continue holding the home button until you iTunes pops up a message telling you that it
>      has detected an iPhone in recovery mode.
> 4. You should see a blank screen. If it isn't blank, you're not in DFU mode.

After entering DFU mode, restore your phone using iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Apple stop signing version 6.1.2 , so you cannot restore 6.1.2.

You can exit recovery mode by using redsn0w.